# Where is the different between NoSuchTableError and ProgrammingError when check if a table existing in Postgres table in Python flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, backend

I want to get the record from the "models" table in db postgers, but I met the case that when I delete the whole table and met the error in @app.errorHanlder() in run.py file.

in my models/controller.py:

```
    """
    get all model information
    Returns：
    spec_records: models list
    """
    logger.info("get all models function starting")
    try:
        # Get all information from the table "models" in database
        spec_records = db.session.query(
            Models.id,
            Models.is_used,
            Models.name,
            Models.train_start_date,
            Models.train_end_date,
            Models.evaluate_start_date,
            Models.evaluate_end_date,
            Models.average_mse,
            Models.comment,
            Models.created_time,
        ).all()
        
        logger.info("get all models function end")
        print(spec_records)
        return spec_records
    
    except NoSuchTableError:
        logger.warning("No such table was found")
        return None
```

This will still causes error, so I replace "NoSuchTableError" to "ProgrammingError" and it worked somehow

```
def get_models_information() -> Row:
    """
    get all model information
    Returns：
    spec_records: models list
    """
    logger.info("get all models function starting")
    try:
        # Get all information from the table "models" in database
        spec_records = db.session.query(
            Models.id,
            Models.is_used,
            Models.name,
            Models.train_start_date,
            Models.train_end_date,
            Models.evaluate_start_date,
            Models.evaluate_end_date,
            Models.average_mse,
            Models.comment,
            Models.created_time,
        ).all()
        
        logger.info("get all models function end")
        print(spec_records)
        return spec_records
    
    except ProgrammingError:
        logger.warning("No such table was found")
        return None
```

Here my model_info.py file:

```
@models_info.route("/models", methods=["GET"])
def get_models_info():
   """
    navigate to the inference model screen
   """
   logger.info("Start function get all models information")
      
   models_list = models_ctrl.get_models_information()
   
   if models_list is None:
        # Case the table is not existing
        ret = render_template(SCREEN_MODELS, message=TABLE_NOT_FOUND)
        return ret

   chubu, kanto, economic = economic_ctrl.get_record()
   
   if len(models_list) == 0:
      message = NO_MODEL_FOUND
   else:
      message = None
    
   ret = render_template(SCREEN_MODELS, models_list=models_list, column_names_list=RENDERED_COLUMNS_NAME, chubu=chubu, kanto=kanto, economic=economic, message=message)
   
   logger.info("End function get all models information")
   
   return ret
```

So the question is why and what is the differents between them ?

Comment: Could you translate the function descriptions and comments to English?

Comment: @Cow I edited already

Answer (score 0):

`ProgrammingError`s are originally raised by the connector package (psycopg2 in this case), because an error has occurred executing connector code, for example because of trying to query a table that does not exist. They are re-raised by SQLAlchemy.

`NoSuchTableError` is raised by SQLAlchemy itself in cases where code executes correctly, but the absence of a table is still a situation that must be handled by application code. For example, say we try to reflect a non-existent table:

```py
tbl = Table('i_do_not_exist', metadata, autoload_with=engine)
```

SQLAlchemy will query the database system catalogue to find the table's details. As the table does not exist, the details will not be found.  This will not raise a `ProgrammingError` because the executed queries all succeed, but SQLAlchemy will raise `NoSuchTableError` because the non-existent table is a situation that must be handled by the application.